# Javascript - Upload multiple images and have a delete button

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

I'm working with python and flask to save my files, and to upload multiple images in js, with the preview and a delete button. When I click on the delete button, I want to delete a specific image. Currently, clicking on the delete button, deletes all.

This is the source code and I understand why the click deletes all.

```
let photo = document.getElementById('imgPhoto');
let file = document.getElementById('file-input');

photo.addEventListener('click', () => {
    file.click();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    
    if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
        $("#file-input").on("change", function(e) {
        
            var files = e.target.files, filesLength = files.length;
            
            for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
                
                var f = files[i]
                var fileReader = new FileReader();
                
                fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
                    var file = e.target;
                    
                    $("<span class=\"pip\">" + "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"/>" + "<br/><span class=\"remove\">Remover imagem</span>" +"</span>").insertAfter("#file-input");
                    
                    $(".remove").click(function(){
                        $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
                        document.getElementById('file-input').value = "";
                    });
                });
                
                fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
            }
        });
    }

});
```

The result when uploaded

[image]

Comment: Instead of `$(".remove").click(function(){ ... }`, try `$(".remove").on("click",function(){ ... }`. The difference - the first one actually ***triggers*** a click, while the second one attaches an event listener.

Comment: same problem.. because the fileInput.value = "" clears everything. I think I would have to handle this via the backend.

in the backend I do:

`for pic in request.files.getlist('pics'):`

if I click on remove in the front, I need to remove it from the back too

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well? This is just so I could give you better advice.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I fixed it in another way :)